# Mapping a place with areas?

Tags: math, computer-science, geo

[image]

I have 2 tables as you can see in the image above. How can I find a place which insides (belongs to) an area or more than 1 areas based on the coordinate of a place and the coordinates of an area? Please give me some advice for algorithm! Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? This site is good at helping you improve your work but not so good at doing it all for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you are trying to determine whether a point is inside a polygon or not..
You can get an idea from the following place:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/
It helped me out during an interview round once...

Basic algorithm idea:
[image: Algorithm]